# Python and MySQL print results

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to teach myself Python but I've hit a brick wall. I need to get a field from MySQL however when I retrieve the data from the database it comes out odd. That's the code below I use.

```
cursor1 = db.cursor()
cursor1.execute("select djname from jerryins_djleaderboard.leaderboard where djname = %s", dj)
result = cursor1.fetchall()
print result
```

It prints out like this:

```
(('cutecrazygirl88\r\n',)
```

However I want it to come out as cutecrazygirl88 as it is in the database. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Except it's *not* "cutecrazygirl88" in the database.

Comment: also you might want to store just your data in the db without anyformatting your value has a newline with it. You can remove these for insert using http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip python strip method

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`fetchall()` returns *all* fields and *all* rows in the cursor. You will need to iterate over the rows and access the fields in order to get at the data.

```
for row in result:
  print row[0]
```

Comment: Silly oversight by me. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

To print everything the table contains with beautifultable:

```
from beautifultable import BeautifulTable
def function_name(result):
     table=BeautifulTable()
     table.column_headers["DJ Name"]
     for row in result:
          table.append_row(row)
     print(table)
```