# python _mssql not returning rows though table has values

Tags: python, sql-server

I have spent about a day on this trying to figure it out but for some reason I can't locate the issue.

I am attempting to run this python from Kali

For some reason the query is returning no results. Am I missing something obvious?

CODE:

```
import _mssql
server = '192.168.1.83'
user = 'sa'
password = 'password123'

print 'connecting'
connection = _mssql.connect(server=server,user=user,password=password,database='WebApp')
print connected
sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM dbo.users"
print connection.execute_row(sqlQuery)
print connection
```

OUTPUT

```
Connecting 
Connected 
Making Query 
None 
<Open mssql connection at 0x7fc1a954d6b0>
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder if the last two prints are correct.  Please look at [this](http://www.mikusa.com/python-mysql-docs/row_results.html), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240706/python-and-mysql-print-results)

Comment: @techspider I've also tried putting it into a forloop and run over the rows but the forloop never enters

Comment: Can you login and issue the query using the `osql` tool without any issues? Is tcp/ip enabled?

Comment: @AnthonyRussell Oh, ok. I tried your code and it worked fine on my system, returning data as expected, the only issue was the `print connected` line that threw an error as connected wasn't defined. I'd check the network protocol configuration in the SQL Server Config Mgr to make sure the correct transport is enabled.

Comment: @jpw oh okay thank you for checking it